# Visual Studio: Include PlugIn but leave out windows part

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to use not the nuget package but the project itself from the media plugin for xamarin forms.

I am adding all the references and upon build (or even clean) i get :

```
 Error: The specified language targets for uap10.0.16299 is missing. Ensure correct tooling is installed for 'uap'. Missing: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/WindowsXaml/v16.0/Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets' (Media.Plugin)
```

I beleive it is looking for the windows SDK which isnt isntalled on my mac and the project itself only supports android and ios.

Using the nuget package, I can check that I only want ios and Android and it works fine, but upon loading the project in as the project it gives me this error.

In the dependencies folder of the project it is still referencing this UAP 10.0.16299 but upon right click all I can do is "refresh".

How can I build my project and leave out this windows crap?

Answer (score 0):

First include the whole project, then edit the CS proj file (right click on solution -> edit project file).

In the first few lines it says: <TargetFramworks...

Remove the unwanted dependencies. They will be gone in the main folder if you save.

Thats it.